# Load testing a web app which has a load balancer

Tags: jmeter, load-balancing, load-testing

I wrote a Jmeter test (that uses different user credentials) to load test a web app which has a load balancer and all it forwards the requests to a single node. How can I solve this?

I used the DNS Cache manager but that did not work.

Are there any other tools which I could use? (I looked into AWS Load testing but that too won't work because all the containers would get the same set of user credentials and when parallel tests are run they would fail.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the load balancing [mechanism](https://kemptechnologies.com/load-balancer/load-balancing-algorithms-techniques) used in your load balancer, it might be the case it's looking into the source IP address and forwarding requests from the same IP to the same backend node. You can try using multiple IP addresses (or [aliases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_aliasing)) and see whether it makes the difference. See [IP Spoofing With JMeter: How to Simulate Requests from Different IP Addresses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ip-spoofing-jmeter) article for more details.

Also adding DNS Cache Manager might be not sufficient, you can try configurign a custom DNS resolver, i.e. [`1.1.1.1`](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-1.1.1.1/) as the DNS server so each thread would resolve the underlying IP address on its own